# What are the alternative of IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis

What are the alternative of IIS? What would be pros and cons of using any server other than IIS for Asp.net application Hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try UltiDev Cassini which is a "free, light-weight and re-distributable web server that can host ASP.NET 3.5, 3.0, 2.0 and 1.1 applications and static HTML sites". (It is based on the original Cassini web server).

now there is UltiDev Web Server Pro UWS which supports ASP.NET 4, 3.x, 2.0 and 1.1.

I dont think there is pros of using UltiDev over IIS